# Is this the longest vanity address in history?

Tags: address

4AbLLLZvjdA3cXr8Xs2LevhActZt3TLGhjiVga99999999999999fvdWrvvfpRHSS78hRznFjpb64BKnn12H5bQFAsifLdj

14 9's in a row is this the longest one in history or is there a longer one? I generated this on a GPU farm running for 6 years with 5000 GPUs on it, actually I got extraordinarily lucky because statistically it would have taken 334 years to reach a 50% chance of generating it at 4 trillion addresses generated per second and 80 possible positions for the string.

Here is a signed message to prove I own it, you can verify on the GUI client:

```
EatingTechnobladesRemainsAt3am on SO owns this address
```

SigV2XPkJtssBFbZLdjvc6csq7nAxfRn76TMY8iNesHXRbdiSH9KpgSeHLxaX3EvbJeboPv5WzYiXZ7Vhh8CoZcXfNrgX